# Rounded Corner TextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i search the web for TextBox with rounded corners and find a xaml code like below:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type my1:CustomTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate >
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" x:Name="Bd" 
BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="#FFF9EAB6">
                            ***<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />***
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFC7B0B0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFC7B0B0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFC7B0B0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Width" Value="Auto">
                                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="27"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>

                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

i want to find out what is

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
```

in detail and why not properly work my template if delete this line from it,
please tell me completely in detail.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part named "PART_ContentHost" contains the control core, this is the textbox itself, besides the adornments. The textbox's code behind will look for it, so if you rename of delete, the control wont work.
In this case, the content is scrollable (as a textbox can scroll text horizontally and vertically).

Comment: thanks for your answer,according to your talk,in the template of any controls,where i write '<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />' code,the actual control place there , and the '  x:Name="PART_ContentHost"  ' means the control itself, in your think i trust?

Comment: yes, basically yes, but not all the controls have the same part names. Its depend on what they do. Some examples at http://xamlcoder.com/cs/blogs/joe/archive/2007/12/13/building-custom-template-able-wpf-controls.aspx  and  http://drwpf.com/blog/category/control-templates/

Answer (score 6):

use this part of xaml deign :

```
 <TextBox x:Name="usernameText" Height="30" Width="300"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" LostFocus="usernameText_LostFocus">
                        <TextBox.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Resources>
                    </TextBox>
```

[image: The shape will be like this]

Answer (score 5):

If you need a simple textbox with rounded corners, you can do it like that:

```
<Border Padding="5" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="White">
    <TextBox Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">This is beautifull ;)</TextBox>
</Border>
```

Comment: Yes, it works because you set Textbox background color to Transparent, but I think it does not work when you set a different background color for TextBox and this background color is different from that set for border. So in this case, how do you face with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `ScrollViewer` contains the actual content of the control. Your control isn't a real textbox, but actually a border (with rounded corners) surrounding a ScrollViewer, into which you would then need to place your text. If you don't need scrolling, you can replace the ScrollViewer with a text box, i.e.:

change

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
```

to

```
<TextBox x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,i changed my code according to above explanation and not work properly yet,

Comment: Can you post the content of your `CustomTextBox` class also? Both will be required in order to fully understand your code.